# Deploying Ionic 2 means stack app to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, mean-stack

So currently I have an Ionic App where only the server is deployed to heroku, but I wanna deploy the entire app, but every tutorial I look up gives me a variety of errors.

This is what my folder structure looks like now, with client containing the ionic app.

```
->App
  ->Client
  ->Server
    ->app
      ->controllers
      ->models
      routes.js
    ->config
    package.json
    server.js
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated. If you need me to post any code feel free. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kind of long so I'll just post the link, but this pretty much explains everything I needed to do.
http://blog.ionic.io/one-mean-ionic-2-todo-app-on-heroku-part-3/